# react native: there is way to change color of radio button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, radio-button

there is way to color the whole button both inside and outside ? coz as it now so its color white in outside and the inside is blue but i want it will be white also .
i use the `react-native-simple-radio-button` and u can see the link.. [the link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-radio-button)

```
import RadioForm, {
  RadioButton,
  RadioButtonInput,
  RadioButtonLabel,
} from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';

                  <RadioForm
                    buttonColor={'white'}
                    animation={true}
                    labelHorizontal={true}
                    labelStyle={{
                      fontSize: 18,
                      left: 15,
                      color: 'white',
                    }}
                    buttonSize={20}
                    radio_props={sort_radio_props}
                    initial={3}
                    onPress={(value) => {
                      setSortRadio({ value: value });
                    }}
                  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when use RadioForm you can set selectedButtonColor prop

example : selectedButtonColor = 'white'